# multiple IPs leased by one user in a linux dhcp server

Tags: centos

in a dhcp server often new users are unable to get IP address.DHCP server IP leases quota became full because multiple IP addresses has been taken by many single user

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. Grow your dhcp scope.
2. Add an additional dhcp scope.
3. Decrease your lease time.

Each of these options have pros and cons, and which one you choose will entirely depend on your technical ability and what equipment you have in your network.

Option 3 is likely the easiest in the short term, but it's really only masking the problem. Eventually you'll need to add more available DHCP addresses, which means implementing #1 or #2.